# Mifare Ultralight authentification using android

Tags: android, authentication, nfc, access-control, mifare

I am creating an android app that stores some user data on NTAG203 tags.

Is there a way we can write a password to the tag and read back the data only when supplied with the password?

Comment: How can you check if the password is correct, without reading it first from the tag?

Comment: S.Pols how can i read the password?

Comment: Do you have a Mifare Ultralight tag or a NTAG203?

Comment: I have a NTAG203 card

Comment: Did you have tried something yourself? This link will help you for general information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: I have tried and I can write NDEF messages to the card and read them. I now want to make the card secure such that its only my app that can read or write to the tag

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible to implement any form of password-based authentication with NTAG203 or MIFARE Ultralight (MF0ICU1) tags. Those are simple memory tags without any cryptographic functionality. You can only set lock bits that (permanently) lock access to data (one lock bit per page and additional lock bits to lock the lock bits).

Depending on your requirements, it might be possible for you to encrypt the data before writing it to the tag (and decrypting the data after reading it from the tag) using a password.

Besides that, other tags in the MIFARE Ultralight and NTAG series have support for a very limited (and not really secure) form of password protection.

Comment: Thanks Roland for your response. How then is it possible to secure NDEF messages on NTAG203 such that it cant be read or be overwritten by another app?

Comment: You cannot protect the NDEF message as a whole from being read or overwritten. What you can do (by means of encryption and digital signature) is to make sure a certain NDEF message that you read from a tag is genuine (i.e. has been *created by you*) and that only you/your app can interpret the data read from a tag.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Finally is there a way of protecting the pages?

Comment: As I wrote above, you can set lock bits (they are located in byte 2 of page 2). For MF0ICU1 and NTAG203 there is one lock bit for each page.